# pop-up fixed alignment in center only works on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm having the following issue on this site :
https://ishop-gadget.com/products/affordable-smart-watch-3-0

When the user clicks to make a purchase a pop up appears like in the picture below but I'd like it to be centred... on the mobile version it works so I'm not sure what I'm missing. i tried inspecting the page with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  .popUpBox {
    width: 350px;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 999999;
    line-height: 3;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: considering using flexbox or grid. They were specifically designed to solve this type of issue.

Comment: Centering is not the problem here. The popup has a `position:fixed` but still scrolls with the page.

Comment: @JeremyThille - saw your answer, agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the parent divs `.page-container` has the following CSS : `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`

This completely messes up the `position:fixed` and your popup starts scrolling with the page.

Remove `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` on the parent, and the popup behaves normally.

Answer (score 0):

Move `div.popupBoxCon` to out of parent divs and put it as a first child in the body.

Give position absolute and it will be always in the center in all devices size.

```css
.popupBoxCon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="popupBoxCon"></div>
 </body>
```